# nested routing in ionic angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm using **Ionic 4**

I have structured my application in pages having following heirary

```
| app
  |- tabs
     |- tabs.page.ts
     |- tabs.module.ts
     |- tabs.routing.module.ts
  |- pages
     |- profile
        |- profile
           |- profile.module.ts
           |- profile.page.ts
        |- profile.module.ts
        |- profile-routing.module.ts
     |- pages.module.ts
     |- pages-routing.module.ts
  |- app.component.ts
  |- app.module.ts
  |- app-routing.module.ts
```

The content of **app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'tabs', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'tabs', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule', canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Then, **tabs.routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    loadChildren: '../pages/pages.module#PagesModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

Which further loads **PagesModule** and content of **pages-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'profile', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'profile', loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#ProfileModule'},
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PagesRoutingModule {}
```

and the content of **profile-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#ProfilePageModule'},
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProfileRoutingModule {}
```

But on visiting

```
/tabs/profile
```

It gives error as

**ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'ProfilePageModule' in './profile/profile.module'**

Replacing     **{ path: '', loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#ProfilePageModule'},** in **profile-routing.module.ts** with **{ path: '', component: ProfilePage}** is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have two "profile.module.ts" files in the profile directory? When you lazy load, be sure that your loadChildren path is pointing to the file that has the "ProfilePageModule" exporting within it, given your error I am assuming that you are pointing to the incorrect "profile.module.ts"

I would say that { path: '', component: ProfilePage} is working since that is eagerly loading, without a demo project to review the code it is hard to tell, but have you tried:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', loadChildren: './profile.module#ProfilePageModule'},
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProfileRoutingModule {}
```